# Slice a vector of vector of doubles in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to perform operations on a select portion of a vector of vectors (matrix).

Image a 5x5 matrix and I would like to create a new matrix object that is a vector of references that will act only the first 4 columns.

I have the following example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<double> > matrix;

void foo(matrix& a, const matrix& b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<double>& aTmp = a[i];
        const vector<double>& bTmp = b[i];
        for (int j=0; j< a[0].size(); j++)
        {
            aTmp[j] += bTmp[j] ;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 
    matrix a (5, vector<double>(5)); // original matrix
    matrix c (4, vector<double>(4)); // some sliced matrix

    for (int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<double>& aTmp = a[i];
        vector<double>& cTmp = c[i];
        for (int j=0; j< a[0].size(); j++)
        {
            aTmp[j]=j;
            cTmp[j]=j;
        }
    }

// Need to change this to have a vector of references to be able to use data from the big matrix into a submatrix. 

    vector<vector<double*>> b (5, vector<double*>(4)); 
    for (int i = 0; i<b.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j< b[0].size(); j++)
        {
            b[i][j] = &a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<b.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j< b[0].size(); j++)
        {
            *b[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

    foo(b, c);

    cout << "I am here" << endl;
   return(0);
}
```

The end result would be to use the vector of references to modify the data in the original A matrix. But currently it is not working as I am using a vector of pointers, which does not allow me to use the function `foo()`.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Your variable b is not double matrix, but it is double * (pointer) matrix.

Comment: You can't call your function foo for pointer matrices, you should call it for non-pointer matrices.

Comment: No, you can not use an std::vector to access element he does not manage. So you must use another class which offer this possibility or restructure your code.

Comment: To extend @gerum's answer, I recommend you to use a matrix library such as Eigen or BLAS like Boost UBLAS with a back-end like ATLAS. Eigen is the easiest way in my opinion.

Comment: You can reduce your code to a few lines by using Eigen C++ matrix library.